# Cache::remember() failure in AppServiceProvider during package discovery

Tags: laravel, redis, composer-php, laravel-artisan

I am using [a package](https://github.com/kylekatarnls/business-day) to deal with business days in Laravel. The documentation asks to register the holidays in some global bootstrap place of the app. I have chosen the `AppServiceProvider` `boot` method to do it. I have additional dates in the database that I want to add to the holiday list.

**AppServiceProvider**

```php
public function boot()
{
    $additionnalExclusions =  Cache::remember('excludedWebPaymentDates', 60 * 60, function () {
        return ExcludedWebPaymentDate::all()->mapWithKeys(function ($model) {
            return [$model->Motif => Carbon::parse($model->Date)->format('Y-m-d')];
        })->toArray();
    });

    BusinessDay::enable(['Carbon\Carbon', 'Carbon\CarbonImmutable'], 'ca-qc', $additionnalExclusions);
}
```

Everything works fine when testing my app in the browser. Where it stops working, is when the `php artisan package:discover --ansi` script is run.
It runs when I run composer dump-autoload, for instance, which is called when a new package is installed or when the app is built via the docker file.

I get the following error:

> Predis\Connection\ConnectionException
>
> php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for redis failed: Temporary
> failure in name resolution [tcp://redis:6379]
>
> at vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/AbstractConnection.php:155

My .env cache config goes as follow:

```
REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

Why does it work in the browser but cause an error when executing the above command? The only thing that made it work was to remove the cache call, which is not ideal because the query would be run on every request.

Comment: The IP doesn't look quite correct. Can you update the question with the value of `REDIS_HOST` and `REDIS_PORT` inside your .env file?

Comment: Docker's DNS resolution works inside containers, probably you are trying to execute the command from the host. Attach to the proper container and execute the command from it. Try `docker exec -ti container_name bash`

Comment: The use of the cache facade works correctly in the controllers and in the AppServiceProvider when interacting with the app via the web.
It does not work when interacting via the console, when calling the artisan command for example.
And you are right, it works when executing the command from inside the container.
However, I am unsure why it is not the case when building my dockerfile.